# Sum the number of firms in one year

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

Suppose I have a dataframe as follows:

```
dt=structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), year = c(2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 
2002L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2001L, 
2002L, 2001L, 2002L)), .Names = c("firm", "year"), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = "data.frame")

dt
 firm year
1   1 2001
2   1 2002
3   1 2003
4   1 2004
5   2 2002
6   3 2002
7   3 2003
8   3 2004
9   4 2002
10  4 2003
11  4 2004
12  4 2005
13  5 2001
14  5 2002
15  6 2001
16  6 2002
```

Now, I hope to sum the number of firms which have exited the market in one year. For example, I want a table like this:

```
 resulttable
     All 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005
2001   3    0    2    0    1    0
2002   3    0    1    0    1    1
```

The first row of resulttable means that 3 firms entered the market in year 2001 and 2 firms exited in 2003, 1 firm exited in year 2004. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tabulate "enter" years and "exit" years with `table`:

```
res <- table(
    dt$year[!duplicated(dt$firm)],
    factor(dt$year[!duplicated(dt$firm, fromLast = TRUE)], levels = unique(dt$year))
)
res <- as.data.frame.matrix(res)
res$All <- rowSums(res)

# > res
#      2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 All
# 2001    0    2    0    1    0   3
# 2002    0    1    0    1    1   3
```

I assumed the `dt` is sorted as provided. If not, one has to sort by year first.

---

#### Here is the suggested way from thelatemail in comment, the results look like this:

```
addmargins(table(
    dt$year[!duplicated(dt$firm)],
    factor(dt$year[!duplicated(dt$firm, fromLast = TRUE)], levels = unique(dt$year))
), 2)

#      2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 Sum
# 2001    0    2    0    1    0   3
# 2002    0    1    0    1    1   3
```

Comment: Nice. You could also use `addmargins(table(...), 2)` to get the sums

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option using `dcast` from `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(dt)`), grouped by 'firm' get the `range` of 'year' into two columns, `dcast` into 'wide' with `drop = FALSE` to avoid removing the unused levels and then sum the values in the row with `Reduce`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(dt)[, as.list(range(year)), firm], V1 ~ factor(V2, levels = unique(dt$year)), 
          drop =FALSE)[, All := Reduce(`+` , .SD), .SDcols = -1][]
#      V1 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 All
#1: 2001    0    2    0    1    0   3
#2: 2002    0    1    0    1    1   3
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a complete solution as the results do not include the missing 'exited' years.  Including them is possible, but a lot of extra steps.  Using two libraries, `dplyr` and `tidyr` we can walk through the process.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dt %>% 
  group_by(firm) %>% 
  summarise(entered=min(year),exited=max(year),count=1) %>% 
  group_by(entered,exited) %>% 
  summarise(count=sum(count)) %>%
  mutate(All = sum(count)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(exited,count,fill=0)

> # A tibble: 2 x 5
>   entered   All `2002` `2004` `2005`
> *   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
> 1    2001     3      2      1      0
> 2    2002     3      1      1      1
```

- `group_by` indicates we want to operate within `firm`
- `summarise` will calculate values once per group, here we get `entered`, `exited` and we produce a counting variable `count`
- Now we group by `entered` and `exited` (the order is important), so we're grouping on the cross of both years
- We now sum our counting variable by the combination of years.  `summarise` here drops the right most level of grouping
- `mutate` creates a new variable, `All` in this case which looks just like the `summarise` but instead of collapsing rows, it computes it within our group, duplicating for duplicate rows.
- `ungroup` removes residual grouping
- `spread` creates a column for each value in our key, populating it with the specified value column, filling in missing values with 0

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different approach using `data.table` which creates the totals *before* reshaping from long to wide format:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, .(entry = min(year), exit = max(year)), by = firm][, All := .N, by = entry][
  , dcast(.SD, entry + All ~ exit, length, value.var = "firm")]
```

> ```
>    entry All 2002 2004 2005
> 1:  2001   3    2    1    0
> 2:  2002   3    1    1    1
> ```

This is already conveying all essential results which the OP verbally described in the question.

---

However, OP's expected result includes columns for the years `2001` and `2003` although they contain only 0. If it is required to show years without entries or exits, this can be accomplished by completing the missing years before computing the totals `All` and reshaping:

```
setDT(dt)[, .(entry = min(year), exit = max(year)), by = firm][
  CJ(entry = dt$year, exit = dt$year, unique = TRUE), on = .(entry, exit)][
    , All := sum(!is.na(firm)), by = entry][][
      , dcast(.SD, entry + All ~ exit, function(x) (sum(!is.na(x))), value.var = "firm")]
```

> ```
>    entry All 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005
> 1:  2001   3    0    2    0    1    0
> 2:  2002   3    0    1    0    1    1
> 3:  2003   0    0    0    0    0    0
> 4:  2004   0    0    0    0    0    0
> 5:  2005   0    0    0    0    0    0
> ```

The missing years are completed by joining with a table of all available combinations of `year` which is created by a *cross join* `CJ()`. The completion introduces a lot of `NA` values in `firm`, therefore `length(firm)` has to be replaced by `sum(!is.na(firm))` as aggregation function.

---

The extension of the resulting wide format can be controlled by the range of years given in `CJ()`. E.g., the empty entry years 2003 to 2005 can be dropped by

```
setDT(dt)[, .(entry = min(year), exit = max(year)), by = firm][
  CJ(entry = min(entry):max(entry), exit = dt$year, unique = TRUE), on = .(entry, exit)][
    , All := sum(!is.na(firm)), by = entry][][
      , dcast(.SD, entry + All ~ exit, function(x) (sum(!is.na(x))), value.var = "firm")]
```

> ```
>    entry All 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005
> 1:  2001   3    0    2    0    1    0
> 2:  2002   3    0    1    0    1    1
> ```

which reproduces exactly OP's expected `resulttable`.

Or, drop also the  empty exit years 2001 and 2005 by

```
setDT(dt)[, .(entry = min(year), exit = max(year)), by = firm][
  CJ(entry = min(entry):max(entry), exit = min(exit):max(exit)), on = .(entry, exit)][
    , All := sum(!is.na(firm)), by = entry][][
      , dcast(.SD, entry + All ~ exit, function(x) (sum(!is.na(x))), value.var = "firm")]
```

> ```
>    entry All 2002 2003 2004 2005
> 1:  2001   3    2    0    1    0
> 2:  2002   3    1    0    1    1
> ```